# XML ResultMap in MyBatis with association

Tags: java, associations, mybatis, dynamicquery, xmlmapper

I see this issue very strange descibed on google or stack. Let me explain.

I have Result Maps in annotations in my interface method. Only in this particular case I need dynamic query, and that is the reason I decided to write the whole mapper for interface in xml file. Below I paste the whole file. The select query should be ok, but I am occuring some difficulties with `<resultMap>`.

On the different websides I was searching for a good explanation of one to one, one to many, many to one association and construct of this result map in general.

I saw there is some kind of possibility to part it into subqueries, subresultmaps. But I have that already done with myBatis annotations, and I want to use it. 
Could you direct me, how should the resultMap be constructed? I dont see need for constructor, discriminator, but it is still shouting... (that is why I added `<collection>` mark) - IntelliJ is underscoring the whole `<resultMap>`saying: `"The content of element type "resultMap" must match "(constructor?,id*,result*,association*,collection*,discriminator?)"`

I know it seems obvious, but I have completly no idea how to do it correctly. Please help me.

xml mapper file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="pl.net.manager.dao.UsageCounterDAO">
    <select id="getUsageCounterList" resultType="pl.net.manager.domain.UsageCounter"
            resultMap="getUsageCounterListMap">
        SELECT * FROM usage_counter WHERE
        <if test="apiConsumerIdsList != null">
            api_consumer IN
            <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="apiConsumerIdsList"
                     open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{item}
            </foreach>
            AND
        </if>
        <if test="serviceConsumerIdsList != null">
            service IN
            <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="serviceConsumerIdsList"
                     open="(" separator="," close=")">
                #{item}
            </foreach>
            AND
        </if>
        <if test="dateFrom != null">
            date &gt;= #{dateFrom} AND
        </if>
        <if test="dateTo != null">
            date &lt;= #{dateTo} AND
        </if>
        <if test="status != null">
            status = #{status}
        </if>
    </select>
    <resultMap id="getUsageCounterListMap" type="">

                    ofType="pl.net.manager.domain.UsageCounter">
            <id property="id" column="id"/>
            <result property="date" column="date"/>
            <result property="apiConsumer" column="api_consumer"
                    javaType="pl.net.manager.domain.ApiConsumer"/>
            <association property="apiConsumer" column="api_consumer"
                         resultMap="pl.net.manager.dao.ApiConsumerDAO.getApiConsumer"/>
            <result property="service" column="service" javaType="pl.net.manager.domain.Service"/>
        <association property="service" column="service"
                     resultMap="pl.net.manager.dao.ServiceDAO.getService"/>

            <result property="counterStatus" column="counter_status"/>
            <result property="ratingProcessId" column="rating_process_id"/>
            <result property="value" column="value"/>
            <result property="createdDate" column="created_date"/>
            <result property="modifiedDate" column="modified_date"/>

    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

Comment: the `<association>` must come after all the `<result>` tags, which means you need to group `<result>` tags and then add `<association>` tags after that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The XSD for the Mapper XML expects that in a `<resultMap>`:

the `<association>` must come after all the `<result>` tags, which means you need to group `<result>` tags and then add `<association>` tags after that.

Secondly, You dont need both `resultType` and `resultMap` in the `getUsageCounterList`. Use any one which in your case is `resultMap`

Third, Your `WHERE` clause in `getUsageCounterList` is broken. What if ONLY first condition is met, then in that case your SELECT will be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM usage_counter WHERE api_consumer IN (1,2,3) AND
```

So as I mentioned in my previous answer to your query you can use `<where>` tags and follow the syntax mentioned in that answer.

Fourth, In the `resultMap` `getUsageCounterListMap` you just need `type` which will be your Java class you are trying to populate, so you can move the `ofType` to `type`.

For **One-One mapping**, you can just use a `<association>` tag, or there's another approach, suppose you have a Java POJOs as given below:

```
public class Country{
    private String name;
    private City capital;
    //getters and setters
}
public class City{
    private String name;
    //getters and setters
}
```

You can write a Mapping in XML as shown below:

```
<select id="getCountries" resultType="Country">
    SELECT c.name, cy.name "capital.name" 
    FROM country c 
    JOIN city cy ON cy.name = c.capital
</select>
```

So Mybatis will make sure to create an instance of `City` and assign the value in `capital.name` to that instance's `name` property.

For **One to Many OR Many to Many** Mapping you can explore the `<collection>` tag of the MyBatis result map. For more information check [Advacned Result Maps](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps) section in the link provided.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will sit right away and try it all out!

Comment: If I want to use <association> tag i one to one so should I write propert, column and resultMap with value of the inteface for field? (How should I inject method inside?) I have seen that webside - advanced result maps, but I found it not exactly complete.

Comment: For example I now have an error:
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection does not contain value for pl.net.manager.dao.RateplanDAO

Comment: It would be very hard to help you out without looking at the code. But if you want to know more about `association`, the same link has a section on that as well. I found that documentation to be self sufficient for straight forward scenarios

Comment: Ok, thank you. Fortunately I also found other way to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

This happens with me -

> The content of element type "resultMap" must match 
>   "(constructor?,id*,result*,association*,collection*,discriminator?)".

1. When there is one or more typos
2. When there is unclosed head tag or unmatched closing tag exists
3. When you wrote `<if></if>` `<case><case>` type of tags inside `<resultMap>` tag at the time mapping for `collection` or `association`
4. When you wrote some tags which are not mean to exists there in some other tags

Hope these hints may help someone.